# PTIJ: With how many minions must a minion daven?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

1. When a [Minion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minions_(film)) davens, does he need to Daven with another Minion?
2. Can a Minon daven with a [Mignon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mignon#Adjective) Minion Minyan, or must it be with a large Minion Minyan?

[image]

### [Source of Pic](http://humansofjudaism.com/humansofjudaism/minion)

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I have a bad feeling if you put together a minyan of minons, the chazan would find some strange, unintentional, untimely end.

Comment: Always invite minions for davening on sukkos, they'll help you with the Ba-**NANUIM!!**

Comment: Actually we pasken *against* the concept of *matza min es mino*, so I guess they should daven alone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/432221/who-can-and-cannot-be-counted-for-a-minyan.html#sthash.97ttOaTJ.dpuf):

> A slave may not be counted for a minyan (SA OC 55:4), nor may one who
>   is half-freedman and half-slave (MB 55:3).

Minions are slaves. They may daven with another minyan that has at least 10 qualifiying Jewish men. But, they cannot be counted as part of a minyan, regardless of how many of them are there. It is a given that a minyan of only minions couldn't exist, either.

Comment: Are Minions in fact slaves?  They switch masters very easily, so it seems to me that Minions are bound through long-term indentures.  This is still covered by the word _aved_, for what it's worth.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Since OP has asked if minions may be counted for a minyan, I assume that he has confirmed that they are Jewish, otherwise, the question is irrelevant. Thus, minions would be freed after 6 years, anyway. If *yovel* comes, they would be freed earlier than that.

Answer (score 3):

The Victorian poet Gerard Manley Hopkins answers this question in his 1877 masterpiece *[The Windhover](http://www.bartleby.com/122/12.html)*, a poem about making it to the hashkama minyan for shacharis:

> I CAUGHT this morning morning’s minion, king-
>   dom of daylight’s dauphin, dapple-dawn-drawn Falcon, in his riding
>   Of the rolling level underneath him steady air, and striding
>   High there, how he rung upon the rein of a wimpling wing
>   In his ecstasy!

This suggests that a minion (here symbolized by a falcon) only needs itself to daven to H'.

This should answer your question. Unless, of course, you are asking about [partnership minions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partnership_minyan). These need to have a second, female minion with them in order to daven.